# What's the size of a folder entry?

Tags: directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-does-size-of-a-directory-mean-in-output-of-ls-l-command)

```
user@~ > ll /tmp/foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4,0K  1 oct.  15:15 bar
```

What are those 4,0K ? Is there somewhere an article about them ?

Comment: There are duplicates scattered throughout the whole network: [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/142893/why-is-the-size-of-a-directory-always-4096-bytes-in-unix) [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012488/when-running-ls-l-why-does-the-filesize-on-a-directory-not-match-the-output-of) and a few others about it. Though, I think this should be the canonical question with an awesome answer.

Comment: The super user answer is fine IMO, I would consider this a duplicate.