# Linux find command - how to find directories by size?

Tags: find, disk-usage

Can `find` return results based on the size of directories?
Below command is working fine as expected -

```
find * -type f -size +10M -exec ls -hlSr {} \+
```

But on applying the same to directories its not returning any results

```
find * -type d -size +10M -exec ls -hlSr {} \+   //no output
```

So want to know if some variation of above is possible.

I know `du` can be used like this --> `du -hs * | sort  -h` to achieve desired output but I am more interested in understanding `find` limitations and usage scenarios.

Comment: [Similar question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1582152/432690).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected.

`find -size` checks the inode size only (remember, directories are also just "files"), not the directory contents. For directories, that will never be more than 10M, so the `find` result will simply be empty.

The inode size is the same you get when you run `stat`:

```
$ du -s dir
61943836851 dir

$ stat -c %s dir
53248
```

So it's not possible with `find` alone.
But you could of course use `find . -type d -exec du -hs {} +` to be able to use `find`'s filter options.

---

Further Reading:

- [Why size reporting for directories is different than other files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234065/why-size-reporting-for-directories-is-different-than-other-files/234293#234293)
- [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-does-size-of-a-directory-mean-in-output-of-ls-l-command?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Why is the size of a directory either 0 or 4096?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503048/why-is-the-size-of-a-directory-either-0-or-4096)

Comment: `For directories, that will never be more than 10M` - from where is this limitation comming? FS or inode table ... etc?

Comment: That is just a guess from my side ... directory files do not hold much information and 10M is **a lot** and **very** far from that. Maybe if you change your block size to 10M then yes, but I'm not an expert for unusual file systems ;-)

Comment: I added some links for further reading.

Comment: thanks for `Further Reading`. That is going out of way to help ppl understand deeper  :-)