# Zip/Tar file compressed to larger size?

Tags: tar, zip, compression

I have 4 files that I want to include them in a **.zip** file.

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:21 CSharp
drwxr-xr-x 11 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:17 gnome-games
drwxr-xr-x  8 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:17 gnome-music
drwxr-xr-x  4 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:18 Test
```

As you can see in total their size is 16K.

### After

I am creating the zip using the command bellow:

```
zip -r myfiles.zip *
```

The file was created successfully but now its size is **20M**, as you can see bellow!

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:21 CSharp
drwxr-xr-x 11 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:17 gnome-games
drwxr-xr-x  8 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:17 gnome-music
-rw-rw-r--  1 skemelio themelis  20M Απρ   4 02:00 myfiles.zip
drwxr-xr-x  4 skemelio themelis 4,0K Οκτ  18 00:18 Test
```

What I've done wrong?

**ps**: Same thing (same size) happened when I try to create a **.tar** using `tar cvf myfiles.tar *`.

Comment: A individual directory always shows the 4k size when viewed with `ls` - what you want to use to check before is `du` - ie, `du -sh *`

Comment: Ok I had no idea why this happens but you are right. Why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: FYI, 4K * 4 = 16K, not 32K.  Also, in this case this is due to a misunderstanding of the size that `ls` reports for directories (that *each* directory was the exactly the same size should have been a hint that maybe `ls` isn't reporting what you think), but in general you should not necessarily be surprised if compression sometimes produces a larger file.  Compression can't compress everything; otherwise you could repeatedly run `zip` on a `.zip` file to get increasingly smaller files.

Comment: Hahaha @jamesdlin, sorry man it was late night and I saw a bunch of video tutorials. :D

Comment: "*I have 4 files...*" - No, you don't. You have 4 **directories** which makes all the difference here.

Comment: Aren't directories files in Unix/Linux @mastov?

Comment: @Themelis I stand corrected. They are "files", they are just not "regular files", which is important here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An individual directory always shows its own size when viewed with `ls` - no matter the size of its contents. What you really want to use to check before is `du` - ie, `du -sh *`.

A good explanation of what the size of a directory means is on this Q&A - [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-does-size-of-a-directory-mean-in-output-of-ls-l-command)

Comment: The size show by ls for a directory is not `false`, it is the size of the directory. However the size of a directory is related to the number of entries in it (possibly the largest number it every had), not the size of those entries.

Comment: So any directory takes 4K of disk space? It feels a lot!

Comment: @Themelis - or more. It is meta-data about the directory and contents, so if your directory has lots of files or subdirectories, etc it will get larger.  Key is to remember the size shown for the directory is about the meta data, not the sum of the sizes of the contents of the directory.